# UIRefreshControl is continuously animating, even when it is not visible

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation, uirefreshcontrol, frank

I've added a `UIRefreshControl` to a `UITableView` and it appears to be continuously animating, even when it is not visible.

Running `frankly_map "view:'_UIRefreshControlModernReplicatorView'", "isAnimating"` through
Frank console reveals that the erroneous view is in fact the private UIKit `_UIRefreshControlModernReplicatorView` which continues to animate off screen.

Any suggestions on why this is happening or how to halt the animation?

Replication Repo => **https://github.com/samst0r/UIRefreshControlFrank**

I've included the important bit of the code =>

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];

    [refreshControl addTarget:self
                       action:@selector(refresh)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    self.refreshControl = refreshControl;
}

#pragma mark - Other

- (void)refresh {

    double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Before you hide it, stop the refreshing with the following code:

```
[refrshControl endRefreshing];
```

Comment: So I've included the code snippets above. I'm already calling `endRefreshing` (for arguments sake after 2 seconds). Any other ideas?